# Array Formula to omit blank rows

Tags: worksheet-function

In excel I have a survey with names appearing in column A and comments about individuals in column H.  Names appear multiple times, in random order, not every survey submitted includes a comment.  In a separate sheet I am compiling the results of all questions for each individual.  I can write an array formula that gives me the individual rows for each individual, and the comment.  What I would like to do is not return the row is the comment is blank.  When the survey is completed I could to a simple sort, but the survey is asking about 30 individuals and will include over 2000 responses.  All other components of the survey update as

Comment: You can't really do this with a formula unless you write your own in VBA

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to use a Pivot Table and filter blank comments

Answer (score 1):

In this example, we assume a header row and use column **I** as a helper column.  
In **I2** enter:

```
=IF(H2="","",1+MAX(I$1:I1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Then in the second sheet, cell **A1**, enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!I:I,0)),"")
```

and copy down.  In the second sheet, cell **B1**, enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!H:H,MATCH(ROW(),Sheet1!I:I,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

You would capture any other columns in the same fashion.  Once the data has been captured, you can sort it any way you please.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are willing to do more than most who present such questions, you have a VERY simple solution.

Just collect all the output rows as you do, including rows for which there is no comment. Select all cells, copy to the clipboard, then `Paste|Special|Values", and sort the data on the comment column. The blanks will sort at the end of the material (assuming A-Z sorting) and you can go to them, select all of them, and delete them.

Then select what remains and sort it as desired. All set.

One can complicate it if there are other concerns. For example, if one needs the rows remaining to have their original order, not a sort of some other kind, just add a column to the right of the data before sorting. In the column place a series:  type a 1 in the first cell, select all the cells that have something to their left, and press `Alt-E-I-S`, then `Enter`. Do what I said above but include this column. After deleting the non-comment rows, select all that remains, including this column, and sort using this column. That restores the original order. Delete this column. All set.

That kind of complication. Just little details to suit things you haven't mentioned in the post.